# How to display function value in another component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display the same time from my stopwatches `formatTime` in the other component so that when I save the value from the input and the current time from the stopwatch will save and show on the list? Can anyone help me I am new to react? The problem is that i don't know how to get the value from formatTime like i got it in Kello.js inside the return by just calling it because it is in a different component.

Kello.js

```
import React, {useState,useRef} from 'react';
    
const Kello = () => {
    const [timer,setTimer] = useState(0)
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)
    const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false)
    const countRef = useRef(null)
    
    const handleStart = () => {
        setIsActive(true)
        setIsPaused(true)
        countRef.current = setInterval(() =>{
        setTimer((timer) => timer + 1)
        },1000)
    };

    const handlePause = () => {
        clearInterval(countRef.current)
        setIsPaused(false)
    };

    const handleResume = () => {
        setIsPaused(true)
        countRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setTimer((timer) => timer + 1)
        },1000)
    };

    const handleReset = () => {
        clearInterval(countRef.current)
        setIsActive(false)
        setIsPaused(false)
        setTimer(0)
    };
    const formatTime = () => {
        const getSeconds = `0${(timer % 60)}`.slice(-2)
        const minutes = `${Math.floor(timer / 60)}`
        const getMinutes = `0${minutes % 60}`.slice(-2)
        const getHours = `0${Math.floor(timer / 3600)}`.slice(-2)

        return `${getHours} : ${getMinutes} : ${getSeconds}`
    };
    
    return (
        <div>     
        <div className='buttons'>
            {
                !isActive && !isPaused ?
                <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
                : (
                    isPaused ? <button onClick={handlePause}>Pause</button> :
                    <button onClick={handleResume}>Resume</button>
                )
            }
            <button onClick={handleReset} disabled={!isActive}>Reset</button>
        </div>
        <p>{formatTime()}</p>
        </div>
    );
    
};
export default Kello;
```

Tallennukset.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ListanJasen from "./Jasen";
import {formatTime} from "./Kello";


const Tallennukset = () => {
    const [items,setItems] = useState([]);
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    
    
    const saveItem = () => {
        if(value === ''){
            return
        }
        setItems([...items, value]);
        setValue("");
    };
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    };
    return(
        <div>
            <input class="title" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} placeholder="Title"></input>
            <button class="tallennus" onClick={() => saveItem()}>Save</button>
            <button class="tyhjennys" onClick={() => setItems([])}>Clear list</button>

           
            <ul>
                {items.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                    <div>
                    <ListanJasen key={index} item={item} /> 
                        
                    </div>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    );
};

export default Tallennukset;
```

Jasen.js

```
import React from "react";


const ListanJasen = ({item}) => {
  return <li onClick={(e) => (e)}>{item}</li>;
};

export default ListanJasen;
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `timer` state up your component tree and passing it down via [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) so both components can access it?

Comment: If i try to move it as it is i get an error because "useState" cannot be called at the top level and also if i move it the "setTimer" is not defined.

Comment: Can you update your question to include details of how you are rendering your `Kello` and `Tallennukset` components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer could be simple.
Move your `formatTime` function to external file, like `timeFormat.js` and make it a common function e.g.:

```js
    const formatTime = timer => {
        const getSeconds = `0${(timer % 60)}`.slice(-2)
        const minutes = `${Math.floor(timer / 60)}`
        const getMinutes = `0${minutes % 60}`.slice(-2)
        const getHours = `0${Math.floor(timer / 3600)}`.slice(-2)

        return `${getHours} : ${getMinutes} : ${getSeconds}`
    };

export default formatTime;
```

then import it where you need it, and use it anywhere.

Then you need to pass on your `timer` variable.
Based on your project structure, you should either pass it with the props, e.g.

Kello.js

```js
...
return(
 ...< Tallennukset timer={timer} />
);
```

then in Tallennukset.js:

```js
import formatTime from './timeFormat.js';
...
const Tallennukset = (timer) => {
...
  <div> {formatTime(timer)} </div>
}
```

or pass it as a context from the top
or use state management library like redux to pass it around
there's many ways to share the variable with multiple components.

Comment: But how does the timeFormat file get the timer value?

Comment: @Steffe30 via the input parameter `timer`.
You need to have your `timer` as more or less global variable to access it everywhere. There's multitude of ways to do it: 1. pass with props from top to bottom; 2. use react context; 3. use some state library, 4. store as variable in URL; 5. save it in browser local storage;... and so on, there's multiple ways to get the data to other components. I'd suggest you go with first one for simplicity